# Laravel registering Service Provider on demand

Tags: laravel, service, provider

i have divided my code into composer packages:
 - core
 - backoffice
 - dashboard
 - and so on

for example: BackOffice requires Core and Dashboard requires BackOffice

Now i have made a singleton which holds a class for the BackOffice MenuItems.

BackOfficeServiceProvider (register):

```
$this->app->singleton(
    'backoffice::view_hooks',
     function () {
         return new ViewHookRegistrar();
     }
);
```

So i can use this singleton to register menu items from the individual packages.

DashboardServiceProvider (boot);

```
$hook = new ViewHook('main_menu', $this->package['name'] . '::menu', 1);
app('backoffice::view_hooks')->addViewHook($hook);
```

But now i have the problem that i do not want to manualy register my ServiceProviders in app.php but with the "autoload way" i have no control which ServiceProvider registers/boots first. (The BackOfficeServiceProvider must come first, it must register the singleton)

My aproach is to register the BackofficeServiceProvider inside the packages ServiceProviders

DashboardServiceProvider (register):

```
if (!app()->getProvider(BackofficeServiceProvider::class)) {
    app()->register(BackofficeServiceProvider::class);
}
```

My question is: Is this the right way or is there a better solution?

Comment: You may have to take into account that on a production server, the laravel settings, config, environment etc are cached. Changing the ServiceProvider settings on the fly may work on development but could run into problems in production state. IMOH, the best way is probably creating parallel settings and let a middleware choose which setting is appropriate to move on with. You could make use Deferred Providers and tagging.

Comment: That's not working, but i dont know why. my hook array keeps empty.
I have created an DeferrableProvider, which registers the ViewHook, with no error i can use it, but it seems always created new if i call it.

$this->app->singleton(
            ViewHookRegistrar::class,
            function () {
                return new ViewHookRegistrar();
            }
        );

app(ViewHookRegistrar::class)->addViewHook($hook); 
dd(app(ViewHookRegistrar::class)->getHooks()) --->empty array